# Problema com id AUTO_INCREMENT no SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

Criei uma tabela no MySQL Workbench com as seguintes definições:

```
CREATE TABLE teste (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
);
```

E quando tento inserir dados na tabela usando:

```
INSERT INTO teste VALUES
('Meu nome', 'meuemail@meuemail.com.br');
```

Dá erro porque não coloco o id, pois eu acreditava não ser necessário já que o id é AUTO_INCREMENT. Tentei fazer colocando o primeiro INSERT INTO com o id e os outros sem o id, mas dá o mesmo erro.
Neste caso, estou fazendo algo errado mesmo ou toda vez que for inserir dados na tabela através do INSERT INTO tenho que inserir o id também?

Comment: Uma dica, coloque tbm a query do `INSERT`

Comment: Se você omite os nomes da colunas no insert sim deve passar um valor para a  coluna id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao omitir os nomes das colunas do insert entende-se que os valores vão ser passados na mesma ordem.

```
INSERT INTO teste VALUES ('Meu nome', 'meuemail@meuemail.com.br');
```

Esse insert é entendido como:

```
INSERT INTO teste (id, nome, email) VALUES ('Meu nome', 'meuemail@meuemail.com.br');
```

Veja que valor especificado para `id` é `meu nome` logo não bate nem com o tipo de dado (int).

A solução para isso é especificar as colunas e os respectivos valores ou passar `null` para a coluna de auto increment.

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta! Resolveu meu problema! :)